# Install R and RStudio in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, rstudio, installation-package

I've just started using Linux and I'm currently trying to install R and RStudio in Xubuntu 16.04. I'm just a little bit confused about the installation of R because some people say we just need to do that:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

And on the other hand, others are saying to add a repository, do the update and then do the command line. For the installation of RStudio it should be okay...

So how can I install R please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently reinstalled R on Ubuntu 14.04 and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2) worked for me:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: Thanks! But now suddenly I'm struggling with the installation of RStudio, it says that it depends on some packages.

Comment: Finally, I figured out the solution for the dependencies, I used: 

sudo apt-get -f install

to ensure those dependencies get installed.

Thanks a lot!